# codemirror onKeyEvent not firing

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am trying to get codemirrors show hint functionality to work I have managed to get it to work with *extraKeys* this loads the getHints function fine but I really want it to work with *onKeyEvent* but this doesn't seem to do anything I can't even get it to send an alert message

```
function getHints(cm) {
// find the words
}

$(document).ready(function(){
CodeMirror.registerHelper("hint", "logger", getHints);
CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(cm) {
    cm.showHint({hint: CodeMirror.hint.logger});
  }
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(
    $("#log").get(0),
    {
        extraKeys: {"Ctrl": "autocomplete"},
        onKeyEvent: function(e, s) {
                var kc = s.keyCode;
                if (s.type == "keyup") {
                    if (kc != 38 && kc != 40 && kc != 13 && kc != 27 && kc != 32) {
                        alert(kc);
                        CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete(e);
                    }
                }
            }
    });
});
```

Heres what I was playing with I have no idea what I am doing wrong even trying to use jquerys trigger doesnt seem to do anything :/
http://jsfiddle.net/f2n74k3s/7/

Answer (score 1):

`onKeyEvent` does not exist in CodeMirror's API. Hence, it is guaranteed not to work. Use `extraKeys`, it is built for this kind of task.

Comment: But its mentioned in the user manuel whats that referring to? http://codemirror.net/2/doc/manual.html

Comment: That's the manual for version 2, which is over two years old.