# Live autocomplete in Codemirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes

It seems that Codemirror plugin *show-hint* is activated by shortcut. I need to implement live autocomplete functionality, i.e. show hints after user entered first letters of keyword. Is there a way to do this with Codemirror?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to do this with CodeMirror. You can see the description of the addon for this [here](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_show-hint). CodeMirror offers the [`hint/show-hint.js` addon](http://codemirror.net/addon/hint/show-hint.js) that allows you to display hints when a keyboard short-cut is used.

You can find additional information on adding hints in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244449/codemirror-autocomplete-custom-list) StackOverflow question as well.

Additionally, you can checkout their demo [here](http://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html).

Comment: I know that I can do this with shortcut, but I need autocomplete to appear when I start typing keyword, like in monaco editor https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html (just start typing anything in right editor)

Comment: In that case, just use the Keymaps to activate `show-hint` http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#keymaps and just have a very permissive set of Keymaps.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function that is fired off after a keyup event. An example of an implementation is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744176/codemirror-autocomplete-after-any-keyup) Stack Overflow answer.